# A question on conditional expectation of dependent random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have two random variables X and Y. But X is determined by Y. For example, $x=e^y$. Then can I claim that $E(X|Y)=X$?

Comment: Yes, up to some minor technicalities that can be swept under the rug in preliminary-level probability theory :)

Comment: Yes. If you know the formal definition of conditional expectation(using sigma algebras) then this is trivial. Otherwise, you can prove this by using density/pmf for a non-rigorous argument

Comment: Informally, if $X=f(Y)$ for a function $f$ (rigourously speaking, a borel measurable function $f$). Then $E(X|Y)=f(Y)=X$.